# recursive function inside for loop

Tags: php, recursion

I m trying to create html in the controller instead of js.
There is an array with unknown depth of arrays.

```
$tree = $repo->childrenHierarchy();
```

and a function who reads the array and returns a string of html with values from array elements.

```
 public function recursive($tree) {
        $html = "";
        foreach ($tree as $t) {
            $html = $html . '<li> <span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-minus-circle"></i>' . $t['title'] . '</span>';
            if ($t['__children'] != null) {
                $html = $html . '<ul>';
                $this->recursive($t['__children']);
                $html = $html . '</ul>';
            } else {
                $html = $html . '</li>';
            }
            return $html;
        }
```

My problem is that i cant hold the total string because everytime the function calls itself the var html is initialised, need to hold the string something like global but cant figure how.

Comment: try it but it is initialse $html evrytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there shouldnt be anything wrong with just storing that value in class property while action ?

```
public $html = "";

 public function recursive($tree) {
        foreach ($tree as $t) {
            $this->html = $this->html . '<li> <span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-minus-circle"></i>' . $t['title'] . '</span>';
            if ($t['__children'] != null) {
                $this->html = $this->html . '<ul>';
                $this->recursive($t['__children']);
                $this->html = $this->html . '</ul>';
            } else {
                $this->html = $this->html . '</li>';
            }
            return $this->html;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking at this a little more, I don't think it really looks like a problem that the `$html` is initialized in the recursive calls. It seems to me that it actually should start as empty for the children. But it doesn't look like you're appending the children to the `$html` string you already have going. I think you need

```
$this->recursive($t['__children']);
```

to be instead

```
$html .= $this->recursive($t['__children']);
```